# How to add a featured image for CMS page in Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I want to add an image from back-end for each CMS page I'm adding in Prestashop, just like we add featured images for posts/page in Wordpress.

I couldn't find any codes/modules which support this feature in prestashop.

Comment: Can you specify where you want to display this featured image in CMS? On the CMS pages or in menu Items as icon? Because unlike Products CMS pages are not displayed in GRID or LIST on pages.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible, but it isn't straightforward. Here are the steps you need to do to implement image upload to the CMS page module. This approach is not the most elegant way to implement this in PrestaShop, but I hope it helps you to move forward.

**Step 1, Update the model so it can contain the image:**

First override 'classes/CMS.php' to 'override/classes/CMS.php'.

```
class CMS extends CMSCore
{    
    // add a public field to store the CMS image
    public $CMS_IMG; 

    /**
    * @see ObjectModel::$definition
    */
    public static $definition = array(
        'table' => 'cms',
        'primary' => 'id_cms',
        'multilang' => true,
        'fields' => array(
        'id_cms_category' =>  array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedInt'),
        'position' =>    array('type' => self::TYPE_INT),
        'active' =>    array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL),
        // Lang fields
        'meta_description' =>  array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'size' => 255),
        'meta_keywords' =>   array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'size' => 255),
        'meta_title' =>   array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 128),
        'content' =>    array('type' => self::TYPE_HTML, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isString', 'size' => 3999999999999),

        // add one image per page        
        'CMS_IMG' =>   array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isString', 'size' => 3999999999999),  ),
    );
}
```

**Step 2, Implement the code needed to upload the image in the backoffice:**

Override 'controllers/admin/AdminCmsController.php' in 'override/controllers/admin/AdminCmsController.php'

```
class AdminCmsController extends AdminCmsControllerCore
{
    public function renderForm()
    {        
        $this->display = 'edit';
        $this->toolbar_btn['save-and-preview'] = array(
            'href' => '#',
            'desc' => $this->l('Save and preview')
        );
        $this->initToolbar();
        if (!$this->loadObject(true))
            return;
        $categories = CMSCategory::getCategories($this->context->language->id, false);
        $html_categories = CMSCategory::recurseCMSCategory($categories, $categories[0][1], 1, $this->getFieldValue($this->object, 'id_cms_category'), 1);

        // Add code to get image url
        $image_url = '';
        $imgName = $this->getImageValue($this->object);
        if($imgName) {
            $image = _PS_IMG_DIR_ . 'cms/' . $imgName;
            $image_url = ImageManager::thumbnail($image, $this->table.'_'.(int)$this->object->id.'.'.$this->imageType, 350,
                $this->imageType, true, true);
        }

        $this->fields_form = array(
            'tinymce' => true,
            'legend' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('CMS Page'),
                'image' => '../img/admin/tab-categories.gif'
            ),
            'input' => array(
                // custom template
                array(
                    'type' => 'select_category',
                    'label' => $this->l('CMS Category'),
                    'name' => 'id_cms_category',
                    'options' => array(
                        'html' => $html_categories,
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('Meta title:'),
                    'name' => 'meta_title',
                    'id' => 'name', // for copy2friendlyUrl compatibility
                    'lang' => true,
                    'required' => true,
                    'class' => 'copy2friendlyUrl',
                    'hint' => $this->l('Invalid characters:').' <>;=#{}',
                    'size' => 50
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('Meta description'),
                    'name' => 'meta_description',
                    'lang' => true,
                    'hint' => $this->l('Invalid characters:').' <>;=#{}',
                    'size' => 70
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'tags',
                    'label' => $this->l('Meta keywords'),
                    'name' => 'meta_keywords',
                    'lang' => true,
                    'hint' => $this->l('Invalid characters:').' <>;=#{}',
                    'size' => 70,
                    'desc' => $this->l('To add "tags" click in the field, write something, then press "Enter"')
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('Friendly URL'),
                    'name' => 'link_rewrite',
                    'required' => true,
                    'lang' => true,
                    'hint' => $this->l('Only letters and the minus (-) character are allowed')
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'textarea',
                    'label' => $this->l('Page content'),
                    'name' => 'content',
                    'autoload_rte' => true,
                    'lang' => true,
                    'rows' => 5,
                    'cols' => 40,
                    'hint' => $this->l('Invalid characters:').' <>;=#{}'
                ),                
                /* Add an fileupload component to the form */
                array(
                    'type' => 'file',
                    'label' => $this->l('Page image'),
                    'name' => 'CMS_IMG',
                    'desc' => $this->l('Upload an image for this page'),
                    'lang' => true,
                    'display_image' => true,
                    'image' => $image_url ? $image_url : false,
                ),                
                array(
                    'type' => 'radio',
                    'label' => $this->l('Displayed:'),
                    'name' => 'active',
                    'required' => false,
                    'class' => 't',
                    'is_bool' => true,
                    'values' => array(
                        array(
                            'id' => 'active_on',
                            'value' => 1,
                            'label' => $this->l('Enabled')
                        ),
                        array(
                            'id' => 'active_off',
                            'value' => 0,
                            'label' => $this->l('Disabled')
                        )
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'submit' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('   Save   '),
                'class' => 'button'
            )
        );
        if (Shop::isFeatureActive())
        {
            $this->fields_form['input'][] = array(
                'type' => 'shop',
                'label' => $this->l('Shop association:'),
                'name' => 'checkBoxShopAsso',
            );
        }
        $this->tpl_form_vars = array(
            'active' => $this->object->active
        );
        return AdminControllerCore::renderForm();
    }

    public function postProcess()
    {
        $languages = Language::getLanguages(false);
        $update_images_values = false;

        foreach ($languages as $lang)
        {
            if (isset($_FILES['CMS_IMG'])
                && isset($_FILES['CMS_IMG']['tmp_name'])
                && !empty($_FILES['CMS_IMG']['tmp_name']))
            {
                if ($error = ImageManager::validateUpload($_FILES['CMS_IMG'], 4000000))
                    return $error;
                else
                {
                    $ext = substr($_FILES['CMS_IMG']['name'], strrpos($_FILES['CMS_IMG']['name'], '.') + 1);
                    $file_name = md5($_FILES['CMS_IMG']['name']).'.'.$ext;

                    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['CMS_IMG']['tmp_name'],
                        _PS_IMG_DIR_ .'cms'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file_name))
                        return Tools::displayError($this->l('An error occurred while attempting to upload the file.'));
                    else
                    {
                        $values['CMS_IMG'][$lang['id_lang']] = $file_name;
                    }
                }

                $update_images_values = true;
                $cms = new CMS((int)Tools::getValue('id_cms'));
                $cms->CMS_IMG = $file_name;
                $cms->update();
            }
        }

        parent::postProcess();
    }

    public function getImageValue()
    {
        $db = Db::getInstance();
        $sql = 'SELECT CMS_IMG FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'cms_lang WHERE id_cms = ' . $this->object->id;
        return $db->getValue($sql);
    }
}
```

**Step 3, Implement the code for the frontend**

Overide 'controllers/front/CmsController.php' in 'override/controllers/front/CmsController.php'

```
class CmsController extends CmsControllerCore
{

    /**
     * Assign template vars related to page content
     * @see CmsControllerCore::initContent()
     */
    public function initContent()
    {
        if(!empty($this->cms->CMS_IMG)) {
            $this->context->smarty->assign('cms_image', _PS_IMG_ . 'cms/' . $this->cms->CMS_IMG);
        }

        parent::initContent();
    }
}
```

**Step 4, use your image in the template**

Now you can, e.g. in cms.tpl use the following code:

```
{if $cms_image != ''}
    <img src="{$cms_image}">
{/if}
```

---

Based on: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/141903-add-custom-field-to-cms-module/

Comment: Few fixes:
0. Must add SQL field manually.
1. Not handling lang properly +not necessary =just set `'lang'=>false` and remove per-lang stuff.
2. In postProcess() check for submit variable: `if(Tools::isSubmit('submitAddcms')..){` (as CMS controller is also used by CmsCategory - if both have img - will trigger for both).
3. 'cms_image' variable isn't necessary - just use attribute: $cms->CMS_IMG.
4. Remove all that `$cms->update()` part (it breaks adding new page) - just set your value in: `$_POST['CMS_IMG'] = $file_name;`..
5. use unique filename for each: `$file_name = $id .'_cms_'. md5(..`.

Answer (score 3):

Adding all these as separate answer, since some moderators seem to reject even most simplest fix/change to original answer as "*This edit deviates from the original intent of the post*" or "*This edit was intended to address the author of the post*" ..right.

---

#### Improving answer by *11mb*

**Step 0, Note that new field needs to be manually added in SQL table (use SQL or PhpMyAdmin structure edit):**

```
ALTER TABLE `ps_cms_lang` ADD `CMS_IMG` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

**Step 1.2, Class cache file needs to be deleted for changes to be active:**

```
/cache/class_index.php
```

**Step 4, use your image in the template**
..
Or more universal form (also usable in category subpages - use `CMS_IMG` attribute (`->` or `.` depends on code):

```
{if isset($cms->CMS_IMG) && $cms->CMS_IMG}
    <img src="{$img_ps_dir}/cms/{$cms->CMS_IMG}">
{/if}
```

---

#### 1. For a non-multiligual field - make these adjustments:

```
ALTER TABLE `ps_cms` ADD `CMS_IMG` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL;

'CMS_IMG' =>   array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => false, ..

'lang' => false,

$sql = 'SELECT CMS_IMG FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'cms WHERE id_cms = ' . $this->object->id;
```

+And remove all that lang stuff in `postProcess()`

---

#### 2. Multiple fixes to `postProcess()`

- code does not correctly save data - should not use `$cms->update();` in `postProcess()` as triggers exception on adding new page, due partial data = just set `$_POST['CMS_IMG']` value..
- should generate unique filename (start with id) for each page.
- should check for isSubmit to avoid processing in wrong chain (if same field name used in CMS categories).

Updated code:

```
public function postProcess()
{
    if ( (Tools::isSubmit('submitAddcms') || Tools::isSubmit('viewcms'))
        && isset($_FILES['CMS_IMG'])
        && isset($_FILES['CMS_IMG']['tmp_name'])
        && !empty($_FILES['CMS_IMG']['tmp_name']))
    {
        $id = (int)Tools::getValue('id_cms');

        if ($error = ImageManager::validateUpload($_FILES['CMS_IMG'], 4000000))
            return $error;
        else
        {
            $ext = substr($_FILES['CMS_IMG']['name'], strrpos($_FILES['CMS_IMG']['name'], '.') + 1);
            $file_name = $id .'_cms_'. md5($_FILES['CMS_IMG']['name']).'.'.$ext;

            if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['CMS_IMG']['tmp_name'],
                _PS_IMG_DIR_.'cms'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file_name))
                return Tools::displayError($this->l('An error occurred while attempting to upload the file.'));
            else {
                $_POST['CMS_IMG'] = $file_name;
                @chmod(_PS_IMG_DIR_.'cms'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file_name, 0666);
            }
        }
    }

    parent::postProcess();
}
```

Comment: You are amazing thankyou!  The only issue was to remove the closing bracket from the line template line: `{if isset($cms->CMS_IMG) && $cms->CMS_IMG)}` to `{if isset($cms->CMS_IMG) && $cms->CMS_IMG}`

Comment: I've not tried to merge both `postProcess()` functions but guess your version does not include the multilingual. Thanks tho for the headache-saver answer.

Comment: I'm still having this bug : When you save a page having an image, it will remove the attached image. So if I just want to edit text, and save it, it will loose the image. Does someone know how to fix it ?:(

Answer (score 2):

The above solutions just do not fit with PrestaShop's philosophy.

Adding a featured image for a CMS page should mimic existing mecanisms (see creation/edition of categories or suppliers logo).

Following is my solution, working for PrestaShop 1.6.1.7. It will add an image field, upload image to img/cms folder and create all thumbnails.

I did not figure out how to delete the image yet, you are more than welcome to comment my answer.
Be careful when updating PrestaShop, files out of the override folder may be updated.

1/ Add the following to **defines.inc.php** (after line 137):

```
define('_PS_CMS_IMG_DIR_', _PS_IMG_DIR_.'cms/');
```

2/ Add the following to **defines_uri.inc.php** (after line 61):

```
define('_THEME_CMS_DIR_', _PS_IMG_.'cms/');
```

3/ Add rules to **.htaccess** file:

```
RewriteRule ^cms/([0-9]+)(\-[\.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/cms/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^cms/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/cms/$1$2.jpg [L]
```

4/ Override **classes/CMS.php** to **override/classes/CMS.php**:

```
<?php
class CMS extends CMSCore
{    
    // Add an id_image attribute to allow further tests in cms.tpl
    public $id_image = 'default';

    public function __construct($id = null, $id_lang = null, $id_shop = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($id, $id_lang, $id_shop);
        $this->id_image = ($this->id && file_exists(_PS_CMS_IMG_DIR_.(int)$this->id.'.jpg')) ? (int)$this->id : false;
        $this->image_dir = _PS_CMS_IMG_DIR_;
    }
}
?>
```

5/ Override **classes/ImageType.php** to **override/classes/ImageType.php**

- Add a public attribute to the class: `public $cms`
- Append to `$definition=>fields`: `'cms' => array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool')`
- In getByNameNType, append to `$types` var: `'cms'`

6/ Override **classes/Link.php** to **override/classes/Link.php**:

```
class Link extends LinkCore
{
    public function getCmsImageLink($name, $id_cms, $type = null)
    {
        if ($this->allow == 1 && $type) {
            $uri_path = __PS_BASE_URI__.'cms/'.$id_cms.'-'.$type.'/'.$name.'.jpg';
        } else {
            $uri_path = _THEME_CAT_DIR_.$id_cms.($type ? '-'.$type : '').'.jpg';
        }
        return $this->protocol_content.Tools::getMediaServer($uri_path).$uri_path;
    }
}
```

7/ Override **controllers/AdminCmsController.php** to **override/controllers/AdminCmsController.php**:

- Append the following to the __contruct method, right before parent::__construct():

  ```
  $this->fieldImageSettings = array(
      'name' => 'banner_img',
      'dir' => 'cms',
  );
  ```
- Append the following to the postProcess method, right after line 351 (in one of the elseif blocks, look for a condition on submitAddcms and submitAddcmsAndPreview):

  ```
  $object = $this->loadObject();
  $image_is_posted = $this->postImage($object->id);
  if (! $image_is_posted) {
      throw new PrestaShopException("image not posted...");
  }
  ```
- In the renderForm method, start with:

  ```
  if (!($obj = $this->loadObject(true))) {
      return;
  }

  $image = _PS_CMS_IMG_DIR_.$obj->id.'.jpg';
  $image_url = ImageManager::thumbnail($image, $this->table.'_'.$obj->id.'.'.$this->imageType, 350,
      $this->imageType, true, true);

  $image_size = file_exists($image) ? filesize($image) / 1000 : false;

  if (Validate::isLoadedObject($this->object)) {
      $this->display = 'edit';
  } else {
      $this->display = 'add';
  }
  ```

and append the following to the attribute `$this->fields_form`, for example after the content field:

```
array(
    'type' => 'file',
    'label' => $this->l('Banner image'),
    'name' => 'banner_img',
    'display_image' => true,
    'image' => $image_url ? $image_url : false,
    'size' => $image_size,
    'hint' => $this->l('Upload a banner image from your computer.')
)
```

- Add and afterImageUpload method:

  protected function afterImageUpload()
  {
      $return = true;
      $generate_hight_dpi_images = (bool)Configuration::get('PS_HIGHT_DPI');

  ```
  $object = $this->loadObject(true);

  /* Generate image with differents size */
  if (($object->id = (int)Tools::getValue('id_cms')) &&
       isset($_FILES) && count($_FILES) && file_exists(_PS_CMS_IMG_DIR_.$object->id.'.jpg')) {
      $images_types = ImageType::getImagesTypes('cms');
      foreach ($images_types as $k => $image_type) {
          $file = _PS_CMS_IMG_DIR_.$object->id.'.jpg';
          if (!ImageManager::resize($file, _PS_CMS_IMG_DIR_.$object->id.'-'.stripslashes($image_type['name']).'.jpg', (int)$image_type['width'], (int)$image_type['height'])) {
              $return = false;
          }

          if ($generate_hight_dpi_images) {
              if (!ImageManager::resize($file, _PS_CMS_IMG_DIR_.$object->id.'-'.stripslashes($image_type['name']).'2x.jpg', (int)$image_type['width']*2, (int)$image_type['height']*2)) {
                  $return = false;
              }
          }
      }

      $current_logo_file = _PS_CMS_IMG_DIR_.'cms_mini_'.$object->id.'_'.$this->context->shop->id.'.jpg';

      if (file_exists($current_logo_file)) {
          unlink($current_logo_file);
      }
  }
  return $return;
  }
  ```

8/ Override **controllers/admin/AdminImagesController.php** to **override/controllers/admin/AdminImagesController.php**

- In the __construct method, append to $this->fields_list: `'cms' => array('title' => $this->l('CMS'), 'align' => 'center', 'type' => 'bool', 'callback' => 'printEntityActiveIcon', 'orderby' => false)`
- In the `__contruct` method, append to `$this->fields_form=>input`:

  ```
  array(
      'type' => 'switch',
      'label' => $this->l('Pages CMS'),
      'name' => 'cms',
      'required' => false,
      'is_bool' => true,
      'hint' => $this->l('This type will be used for CMS banner images.'),
      'values' => array(
          array(
              'id' => 'cms_on',
              'value' => 1,
              'label' => $this->l('Enabled')
          ),
          array(
              'id' => 'cms_off',
              'value' => 0,
              'label' => $this->l('Disabled')
          ),
      )
  ),
  ```
- In `initRegenerate` method, append to `$types` var: `'cms' => $this->l('CMS pages')`
- In the `_regenerateThumbnails` method, append to `$process` array: `array('type' => 'cms', 'dir' => _PS_CMS_IMG_DIR_)`

9/ Update your CMS page template **cms.tpl** with something like this:

```
<!-- Check out the default theme's category_header.tpl for original PrestaShop code -->
<div class="cms_banner"{if $cms->id_image} style="background:url({$link->getCmsImageLink($cms->link_rewrite, $cms->id_image, 'large')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}) right center no-repeat; background-size:cover; "{/if}>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Your content here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the loose of the image when you're updating the datas. (This appends with the 1.7) I suggest the following improvement in the postProcess method :

```
public function postProcess()
{
    $languages = Language::getLanguages(false);
    $update_images_values = false;
    $cms = new CMS((int)Tools::getValue('id_cms'));

    foreach ($languages as $lang)
    {
        if (isset($_FILES['CMS_IMG'])
            && isset($_FILES['CMS_IMG']['tmp_name'])
            && !empty($_FILES['CMS_IMG']['tmp_name']))
        {
            if ($error = ImageManager::validateUpload($_FILES['CMS_IMG'], 4000000))
                return $error;
            else
            {
                $ext = substr($_FILES['CMS_IMG']['name'], strrpos($_FILES['CMS_IMG']['name'], '.') + 1);
                $file_name = md5($_FILES['CMS_IMG']['name']).'.'.$ext;

                if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['CMS_IMG']['tmp_name'],
                    _PS_IMG_DIR_ .'cms'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file_name))
                    return Tools::displayError($this->l('An error occurred while attempting to upload the file.'));
                else
                {
                    $values['CMS_IMG'][$lang['id_lang']] = $file_name;
                }
            }

            $update_images_values = true;
            $cms->CMS_IMG = $file_name;
            $cms->update();
        }
        else
        {
            $_POST['CMS_IMG'] = $cms->CMS_IMG;
        }
    }

    self::saveProducts();
    parent::postProcess();
}
```

That adds an else condition to the original one

Answer (score 0):

```
 // add one image per page        
    'CMS_IMG' =>   array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isString', 'size' => 3999999999999),  ),

 Above argument can not create a field on cms_lang table.

 So system can gives the following error

 Unknown column 'cms_image' in 'field list'

 if ($webservice_call && $errno) {
        $dbg = debug_backtrace();
         WebserviceRequest::getInstance()->setError(500, '[SQL Error] '.$this->getMsgError().'. From '.(isset($dbg[3]['class']) ? $dbg[3]['class'] : '').'->'.$dbg[3]['function'].'() Query was : '.$sql, 97);
     } elseif (_PS_DEBUG_SQL_ && $errno && !defined('PS_INSTALLATION_IN_PROGRESS')) {
         if ($sql) {
             throw new PrestaShopDatabaseException($this->getMsgError().'<br /><br /><pre>'.$sql.'</pre>');
         }

         throw new PrestaShopDatabaseException($this->getMsgError());
     }
 }
```